# Compare the first 20 lines of two files

Tags: manjaro, file-comparison

What is an easy way I can compare the first 20 lines (or `n` lines) of two files?

I had set up an automated `pg_dump`, but it turns out the dumps being created are corrupt and now won't restore.

I still have a good dump file from a year ago, and I want to compare the first 20 lines between the two files.

What's an easy way of doing this?

I'm on Manjaro Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a shell with process substitutions (`<(...)`), e.g. `bash` or `zsh`:

```
diff <( head -n 20 file1 ) <( head -n 20 file2 )
```

This run `head -n 20` on each file to get the first 20 lines of each, in two separate process substitutions.  Each process substitution will be expanded to *the pathname of a file* where the output of the command within may be read from (these files are temporary and are removed later).

The `diff` utility is then called to compare these two sets of data.

Without a process substitution:

```bsh
head -n 20 file1 >file1.short
head -n 20 file2 | diff file1.short -
rm -f file1.short
```

This creates a separate file from the 20 first lines of one file, and uses that with `diff` while the 20 first lines of the other files are read from standard input.

You may want to use `-c` or `-u` or some other option with `diff` in the commands above to get the diff format of your choice (see the `diff` manual).

---

If the files are compressed, then you will have to uncompress the data:

```bsh
diff <( gzip -d -c <file1 | head -n 20 ) <( gzip -d -c <file2 | head -n 20 )
```

or, without process substitutions:

```
gzip -d -c <file1 | head -n 20 >file1.short
gzip -d -c <file2 | head -n 20 | diff file1.short -
rm -f file1.short
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Kusalananda, does diff work with binary files? all I get is: `Binary files /proc/self/fd/11 and /proc/self/fd/12 differ`

Comment: @J86 Are your files not database dumps in text format? Are they possibly compressed?

Comment: No, they're definitely not in text format, they were created using `pg_dump -Fc`

Comment: Thanks, would this only work if the files are compressed? Cause right now I'm getting `gzip: stdin: not in gzip format`

Comment: @J86 Yes, the last part of my answer would only work if the files are compressed using a `gzip` compression. If you can't get it to work with my code, then you will have to be a whole lot more explicit about what you file are, what format they are on, how they were created, etc., because nobody would be able to work with totally unknown files that they can't see.

Comment: if the files are mostly text, then maybe `diff -a` will be enough